# Genymotion problems in windows 10

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion, windows-update

I have a problem about Genymotion after updating my OS to Windows 10, fistly it did not open with this error: Virtualization engine not found. Plugin loading aborted. Also unable to load virtualbox engine. After all I tried to upload Genymotion version 2.0.3 and system worked but I could not upload any virtual device. Then uploaded 1 virtual device however it did not worked. Help Please.. Thank you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You may try the following process:

1. Run **VirtualBox** as administrator (By default is installed in C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox)
2. Go to File -> Preferences -> Network (Left Navigation List) -> **Host-only Networks** (on the right tab)
3. Select an **adapter** and click **edit** (the small screwdriver on the right)
4. On "**Adapter**" tab set

   - IPv4 Address: **192.168.1.201**
   - IPv4 Network Mask: **255.255.255.0**
5. On **DHCP Server** Tab set

   - Server Address: **192.168.1.100**
   - Server Mask: **255.255.255.0**
   - Lower Address Bound: **192.168.1.101**
   - Upper Address Bound: **192.168.1.199**
6. Click Ok (Host-only Network details), click Ok (VM Settings)
7. Open Genymotion (as Admin), install a new virtual device (you have deleted all past devices) and start it

It worked with **Genymotion 2.5.3** and **VB 4.3.12**, hope it helps !!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you see if it works with latest Genymotion 2.8.0 and VB?

Answer (score 15):

In my case (Windows 10 with VirtualBox 5.0.10 and Genymotion 2.6.0) i had to:

- Go to **network connections**  (run control netconnections from cmd)
- Right click and properties on **VirtualBox Host-Only Network**
- Enable **VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver**

Also some times it helps to delete the virtual device and to download it again.

Comment: my pleasure, also remember that if you badly need an android emulator, Bluestacks will do the trick

Answer (score 6):

UPDATE: This is fixed in the latest Genymotion and doesn't happen to me any more.

---

NOTE: this is using Genymotion 2.5.3, VirtualBox 5.0.0 r101573 and updated Windows 10 as of today.

I'm having all kinds of problems as well, I finally managed to get it working:

- Delete genymotion and virtualbox
- Remove any unremoved files in folders like AppData and Program Files
- Restart
- Install Genymotion
- Install VirtualBox latest
- Run Genymotion as admin, just in case
- Install an image that I didn't try before to make sure it's not using any cached data.

It worked fine.

Sometimes, I still freezes and stops working if I try to start a second device. The solution is to:

- Close Genymotion, Android studio, etc
- Force kill adb.exe and any VirtualBox processes.
- Start Genymotion again and start a device.

Comment: Thank you Space Monkey, image is ova file? I used many solution for this but no solution was useful.. it is still problem for me.

Comment: I got it to work again by making sure I kill "adb.exe" before starting Genymotion. By "Image" I meant adding a new device from the list, that's all.

Comment: Can you rejigger this answer to make it clear what solution it provides? At present it reads more like a "me too" comment.

Comment: Don't forget to "run as administrator". It was problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Install the latest version of Genymotion(2.5.3) can solve the problem.

I've send a email to Genymotion to ask this problem, and I got this reply：

"
Damien (Genymobile) 
Jul 30, 10:25 
Hi,
Thanks for your report! It will help us to improve our products.
Old version of Genymotion were not working correctly with Windows 10. This has been fixed in Genymotion 2.5.3.
Please download the latest version of Genymotion and try again.
Best regards,
Damien
Genymotion Support Team
"

Comment: Pasting the whole email is not really needed. I would say just the recommendation plus your source

Comment: It still has issues, starting a second device for example makes it hang.

Comment: I have reset my OS ,then installed Genymotion and Vbox, it worked.

Comment: so you have to use the latest version of VBOX (5.x.x), it should work;)

Answer (score 2):

Refer to this virtualbox thread:
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14040

For me, as other answers suggested, using genymotion 2.5.3 and latest vbox works fine.

You can find latest test builds at https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT** Vbox now officially supports windows 10 and genymotion 2.5.4 also supports Vbox version (5.0.4) on Windows 10
see https://www.genymotion.com/#!/release-notes

Comment: Perhaps you could improve you answer a bit. Instead of just giving a link.

Comment: You just saved my day! As an improvement to answer, here I got several "Virtual boxes ... devices", I've cleared them all.

Comment: Thanks @guisantogui!

Answer (score 2):

Start Genymotion 2.5.3 in compatibility mode with Windows 8 - it solves the problem for me. VirtualBox 5.0.0 r101573 and Windows 10 Home (all for x64).

Answer (score 1):

You have just to update your VirtualBox, use a 5.x.x VBOX version it should work normaly ;)

Comment: I was using 5.0.0 and was not working. Then updated to the latest (5.2.6) and it works now!! I tried everything else without success (did not tried the accepted solution, though). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VirtualBox. File -> Preferences -> Network -> Select Host-only Networks.

Select one of the Ethernet Adapters -> Click the tool on bottom right of screen. The third button on the right.

Enter the following:
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.201 IPv4
Network Mask: 255.255.255.0.

No need to have DHCP Server selected. Hit OK and now you are good to go.

If you haven't done so, make sure to go to Settings and set Version to Windows 10. Also, update Genymotion to the most current version.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps

- Update your Genymotion to 2.5.3
- Update your VirtualBox to 5.0
- Go to your virtualbox settings, under the general tab on the top left , set the version to windows 10

i tried this , and it worked well

Answer (score 0):

Install Virtualbox Testbuild [lastest](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds) -> Install Genymotion without Virtualbox ->
Right click Genymotion -> Properties -> Compatibility -> In Compatibility mode, check Run this program in compatibility mode for and selected Windows 8 -> It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me. I saw in one post that genymotion 2.0.3 will work out of the box. And it did. The only change I made was:
1. Uninstalled genymotion latest version and Vbox and restarted
2. Installed the last 4.x.x version of vbox
3. Installed genymotion 2.0.3 without installing vbox

its working fine for me now.