# System gets restart on starting of Genymotion emulator

Tags: android, windows-10, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

My system gets restart, when i start Genymotion emulator. Its showing following screen;

[image]

I am not able to findout reason behind this. Please provide some solution to solve this error;
I am using **windows10**, **Genymotion-2.8.1** and **VirtualBox-5.1.18-114002-Win**

Comment: Is your virtual box updated ?

Comment: try to disable hyperV http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line

Comment: @MM after disabling hyperV, when i try to open emulator its giving error like;

"Unable to start Virtual device. VirtualBox cannot start the virtual device."

Comment: @Lokesh Virtual box is updated.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709084/genymotion-problems-in-windows-10 . Try to reinstall it.Also try searching(google) system service exception genymotion

Comment: For this problem there can be various reason like corrupted file system, memory issues and bad drivers. First of all make sure you do have the updated genymotion and all the drivers are updated. And also paste the stop error information.

Comment: @MM Thanks yours solution works for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.Try to disable HyperV

[How to disable Hyper-V in command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line)

2.Try to reinstall genymotion.

Also See:
[Genymotion problems in windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709084/genymotion-problems-in-windows-10)

Also try searching(google) system service exception genymotion